# How can I nest resource using rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to add follow system to my rails app.
I tried this code:

devise_for :users, skip: :all
as :user do
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  # Here I put my custom routes

end

and I get an error that the user resource has already been defined. And when i remove the user resource like so

devise_for :users, skip: :all
as :user do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end

# Here I put my custom routes
end

I get "member must be nested under a resource." error.
I've tried adding :path => "accounts", it didn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding routes that have nothing to do with Devise.  Devise is focused on authentication and you're goal here has nothing to do with authentication.

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  member do
    get :following
    get :followers
  end
end
```